# How to migrate from INGRES to MS-SQLServer

Tags: sql-server, database, odbc, ingres, embedded-sql

we have serveral C (ANSI-C) processes on a intel-based solaris server which connect to an ingres db through embedded sql. Now we want to migrate the code to ms-sql server.
I have already found OBDC drivers/libraries for solaris on the net, like

https://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc-sql-server-driver/index.html.de

http://www.sqlapi.com/index.html

but none pre-compiler for ms-sql server for ansi-c.

- Can I migrate the embedded SQL code to T-SQL for MS-SQL (Tool-based)?
- Is there an official driver for MS-SQL Server for ANSI-C on solaris?

Thanks for you help!